# Select anchors only having class "doc-count" in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am Jquery newbie and learning it these days. I have below HTML -

```
<div class="doc-sizer fr" id="doc-sizer-fr-document">
<a href="#" value="5" class="doc-count current">5</a>
<a href="#" value="10" class="doc-count">10</a>
<span class="doc-count desc"> doc per page</span>
</div>
```

i  require to write a jquery selector which pick the   having class "doc-count" only and exclude .

Could somebody help me to achieve this.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: start from http://learn.jquery.com/  & http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: Thanks Arun for sharing the URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$("a.doc-count")
```

This will give you an array of jQuery objects that you can either iterate over:

```
$anchors = $("a.doc-count");
$anchors.each(function(){
  console.log(this.href);
});
```

or preform a bulk operation on:

```
$("a.doc-count").css("color", "green");
```